# Cloud Functions for Firebase database trigger?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Any idea why I can't use childByAutoId?

```
exports.addPersonalRecordHistory = functions.database.ref('/personalRecords/{userId}/current/{exerciseId}')
    .onWrite(event => {

       var path = 'personalRecords/' + event.params.userId + '/history/' + event.params.exerciseId;
       var reference = admin.database().ref(path).childByAutoId();

       reference.set({
            username: "asd",
            email: "asd"
          });
  });
```

Error

```
TypeError: admin.database(...).ref(...).childByAutoId is not a function
    at exports.addPersonalRecordHistory.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:18:111)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`childByAutoId()` is for the iOS SDK.  For `admin.Database()`, use [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#push).

```
var reference = admin.database().ref(path).push();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
exports.addPersonalRecordHistory = functions.database.ref('/personalRecords/{userId}/current/{exerciseId}').onWrite(event => {
  var path = 'personalRecords/' + event.params.userId + '/history/' + event.params.exerciseId;
   return admin.database().ref(path).set({
    username: "asd",
    email: "asd"
  });
});
```

Comment: but that's not how I want to structure my data